# Security consideration for whitelisting IPs for Node endpoints

Tags: node.js, routes, whitelist

I have an application that will require a few behind-the-scenes processes to be triggered (e.g. updating the database with external items etc.). I would like to set these up in Node, but do not like the idea of exposing API endpoints to the outside world. 
Having looked around it seems like there are a few ways of whitelisting certain IP addresses for Node endpoints (there's even a [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ipfilter) if you want to go down that route), but is sticking a filter at the start of your route function a secure way to go? e.g.

```
router.post('/hidden', (req, res) => {
   //if ip address === example then next()
}, validation, middleware, etc)
```

I can't see a way of hacking this, but at the same time it feels a bit questionable.

Preference would obviously be a separate microservice with a firewall round it, but the time involved setting this up may be prohibitive for the time being.

I hope this doesn't come across as a lazily open-ended question - specifically, I suppose I'm interested in how this approach could go wrong...

Comment: Bear in mind that IP addresses can be [spoofed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing) with very little effort. IP filtering might be helpful as part of a larger security strategy, but on its own it's basically worthless.

Comment: Would this not also apply to IP whitelisted firewalls (such as those commonly used on AWS)?

Comment: I have no idea how the people at Amazon handle it, to be honest! But that's probably why they're working there and I'm not :p But yeah, I don't mean to suggest that all IP whitelists are useless - just that there's a lot more to it than an equality check.